# Удаление HTML тэгов с регулярного выражения

Tags: html

<a\b[^>]+?href=["'][a-z]+://[^>]+>, подскажите пожалуйста, что добавить в данное выражение для удаления тэгов? Нужно только URL получить. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно же просто достать урл. Под это регулярки заточены. Какой смысл удалять все остальное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно только URL получить

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(e) {
  let url = e.getAttribute('href');
  console.info(url);
});
```

```html
<a href="file:/gallery/pictures/summer.html">file:/gallery/pictures/summer.html</a><br>
<a href="http://site.ru/">http://site.ru/</a><br>
<a href="https://site.ru/">https://site.ru/</a><br>
<a href="https://site.ru/#anchor">https://site.ru/#ahchor</a><br>
<a href="ftp://pgu/directory/library">ftp://pgu/directory/library</a><br>
<a href="mailto:nika@gmail.com">mailto:nika@gmail.com</a><br>
<a href="http://site.ru/pages/tips/tips1.html">http://site.ru/pages/tips/tips1.html</a>
```